# Can't use apply function(kotlin) in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class Test {
    private fun test(context : Context){
        val recyclerView = RecyclerView(context).apply {
        }
    }
}
```

It throws error like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you added dependency ```implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"```

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani Thanks! I did. I solved my issue. All I did was to clear the cache :D